# How to disable paste protection in Mozilla Firefox Developer Console?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have noticed that in recent versions of Mozilla Firefox there is a super, super annoying bug that disables pastes into the developer console. This has to be the single worst idea ever.

However, I have tried to allow it by typing in the text that it wants me to but I can still not paste in stuff and I think I'm soon going to be so annoyed that I have to switch browser since I use the developer console every day. I really like Mozilla and Firefox and do not want to switch for such a silly thing.

So how to turn off this crappy "feature" for good? I really hope there is a setting but I can't find one. If not I guess I'll have to open a bug ticket for it.

**My firefox version is**: 32.0.3

If any Firefox developer sees this, please stop implementing features that makes developers go mad. No non-developer is in that developer console anyway and if they get tricked into pasting something there it is *not* your fault.

Comment: Your firefox version?

Comment: Sorry, @Mohamadshiralizadeh it's 32.0.3

Comment: Mine is 32.0.2 but I don't have ant problem. Do you try to reinstall firefox?

Comment: Whops, read too quickly it's 32.0.3. No I found this thread: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=994134 that talks about implementing it. The message say it's going away but it's still there. Both on my Mac and my Windows installations.

Comment: @Jonathan `Welcome to Chrome` is an answer?!!

Comment: I use *drag'n drop* when or where *cut'n paste* won't work!

Comment: @F.Hauri drag'n drop? Cmon.. I'm a developer, not a ballet teacher :(

Comment: I hate having to work with mouse, but if this could help to workaround some bug... This could be a way... I've find this as an efficient trick when something wrong.

Comment: To clarify the answer above, "dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled" should be set to false. This worked for me.

Comment: If any Firefox developer sees this, they must know we love them soooo much =*

Answer (score 133, accepted):

> Since you are automating things, you can get rid of this feature by
>   setting the setting `devtools.selfxss.count` to a high number like 100.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=994134#c82

This settings can be changed on page `about:config`.

Comment: Possibly easier solution (can't try as I've done the solution in this answer before): Type "allow paste" in the console(?) as the warning message says (not sure if this is the correct translation, I'm using the German Firefox)

Comment: In English FF it need input in console 'allow pasting', but is very annoying solution. Not for every hour usage.

Comment: Seriously? You'd have to input this *every* time? Wow, the FF devs can't tell me they are using this themselves... oO (luckily, your answer works fine! :) However, I'd like to have an easier option...)

Comment: Seriously. I debug xpi addon. Resetup it after changes need restart browser. And input this words again and again.

Comment: It would be nice to note how you change this setting, by visiting `about:config`

Comment: According to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=994134#c82 , it's sufficient to set this setting to 10.

Comment: It would be useful to mention the setting name.

Answer (score 54):

If you want to fix it only temporarily you can do this:

1. Open console and type "allow pasting" and hit enter.
2. Now try to paste something. It will paste.

The Same solution is provided by Mozilla when we try to paste.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: At the time it didn't work because it was expecting `allow paste` and I was automating it so next time I spun up a browser the settings were gone.

Comment: While this does, in fact, work it's not practical that I type that every time I work on code :(

Comment: Note that this is affected by the host's language. So in my case I had to write "permitir pegado".

Comment: This didn't help. Not in any way at all.  (I didn't downvote.)  I don't want to type "allow pasting" — it takes long, I need to do it thousands of times over the weeks and months ... causing me to search for how to disable this.

Comment: I use my Firefox in Telugu, but keep English as the default input method. Changing the input type and typing పేస్టింగ్ అనుమతించు into the field every time I open dev-tools is not easy!

Comment: Per a below comment, "allow pasting" no longer works.  At this time, changing the "devtools.selfxss.count" option still works (Firefox v87).

Comment: It worked for me, is there any way to disable pasting?

Comment: One needs to *type* "allow pasting" and not *paste* it!

Answer (score 22):

Actually as of May 21, 2020 "allow paste" "allow pasting" and `devtools.selfxss.count` do not work. I already migrated from Chrome because of backdoors literally built into the browser by developers. I'd really rather not have to do that again already.

**Solution:**

The solution I found was to use `about:config` and set `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` to `false`. Worked for me, this should work.

Comment: 2021 update. FF v88.0.1. "allow paste" didn't work but "allow pasting" did.

Comment: This is still the best answer, it provides a permanent , alternative solution via configs

Comment: It wouldn't be such a pain if they at least made it consistent.

Comment: Setting `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` to false breaks functionality in some web apps - for example, Discord won't accept pasting any more.

Answer (score 5):

[**Solved**]*Firefox Paste Not Working in Console*

**Solution:**
Open console and type "*allow pasting*" and hit enter.
maybe it give you an error but now you can paste it.

refer the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekN2i953Nas&ab_channel=BrainyTechz